# Is there a way to avoid storage overhead when using a function as a callback?

Tags: c++, c++20

Given the following setup:

```
// ***** Library Code *****
#include <concepts>

template <std::invocable CbT>
struct delegated {
  explicit constexpr delegated(CbT cb) : cb_(std::move(cb)) {}

 private:
  [[no_unique_address]] CbT cb_;
};

// ***** User Code *****
#include <iostream>

namespace {
  inline constexpr void func() {}
}

struct MyFunc {
  constexpr void operator()() const {}
};


int main() {
    void (*func_ptr)() = func;

    auto from_func = delegated{func};
    auto from_func_ptr = delegated{func_ptr};
    auto from_lambda = delegated{[](){}};
    auto from_functor = delegated{MyFunc{}};

    std::cout << "func: " << sizeof(from_func) << "\n";
    std::cout << "func_ptr: " << sizeof(from_func_ptr) << "\n";
    std::cout << "lambda: " << sizeof(from_lambda) << "\n";
    std::cout << "functor: " << sizeof(from_functor) << "\n";
}
```

It produces, on GCC-x86-64 ([See on godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cvYPM6PjE)):

```
func: 8        <----- Unfortunate
func_ptr: 8    <----- Fair enough
lambda: 1      <----- Neat
functor: 1     <----- Neat
```

None of this is particularly surprising.

However, it's frustrating that an undecayed lambda is preferable to using a function. And adding a note that `delegated{[]{func();}}` reduces the storage overhead is not exactly user-friendly, and makes for a very poor library interface.

Is there a way to do away with the storage overhead in the `func` case while maintaining a consistent user-facing API?

My current suspicion is that this is not possible without resorting to macros, on account of `func` not having, or decaying into, any type that would distinguish it from other functions with the same signature. I'm hoping that I overlooked something.

**N.B.** I get that something along the lines of `delegated<func>()` is a possibility, but unless I can prevent `delegated{func}` while still allowing `delegated{func_ptr}`, then that would be practically pointless.

**Edit:** To clarify the context a little bit: I am writing `delegated` in a library, and I don't want users of said library to have to worry about this. Or at least have the process be compiler-assisted instead of being documentation-dependant.

Comment: Would you be adverse to having a factory function, and use it like `auto my_delegate = make_delegate(something);`?

Comment: @NathanOliver That would be great! (as long as it's not a macro) I tried a few things in that direction before posting the question but haven't had luck yet.

Comment: 8 bytes is the size of the address of the function. That's the natural pointer size on x86-64.  So the size of a lambda is deceiving because you can't actually call back through the size of the compiler generated context storage structure. The method to be called is still going to be 8 bytes long when stored on x86-64. In fact it has to be equivalent to `sizeof(void*)` on POSIX machines. So what's the actual goal here?

Comment: @Mgetz The goal is that I want to avoid writing "If you use a function as a callback, wrap it in a lambda" in the documentation of the library.

Comment: @Frank then just have a template take an invokable, any dynamic function pointer will always have a size of at least 8 bytes on this platform. A template works because it's technically compile time, and can take either a lambda or a function address. Long story short: don't be fooled by the `sizeof` a lambda it's telling you the size of the context structure, not the pointer to the method.

Comment: Where is this storage overhead occuring?  Is it only occuring on the stack while calling?  Because storing the lambda will require overhead much larger.  Do you value the size of the instruction code at all?  The cost there for lambdas will be larger than the cost of a single function pointer on the stack.  In short, what practical* cost are you attempting to deal with?0 here?  One number being bigger than another isn't a practical cost.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yes, I have done my homework on this. Yes, these are often heap-allocated objects. Yes, size matters as composites including multiples of these objects do get copied around. Yes, it has been demonstrated that in optimized builds, within the real context, the resulting assembly is exactly the same for lambda and function references (apart from offsets being different due to the sizeof difference).

Comment: @Frank So, a stateless lambda object *must* have which code is called be stored in the program code of all code that calls it.  For a function pointer, the same calling code can be used for every calling code that uses it.  If your optimized code is not actually following the pointer, your compiler is proving which pointer it is calling and skipping actually using the pointer.  To me, this is *extremely strong evidence* that you putting that pointer on the heap is a design flaw.  And multiple copies of a stateless lambda is ... pretty pointless?

Comment: On the other hand, if you are doing *type erasure* of the `delegated` object (so the compiler doesn't know what the function does), it isn't tricky to handle function pointers in a way that saves you the overhead; especially if you are willing to hack the ABI.  Because the process of erasing overhead has some wiggle room in it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no objects of function types. The type will be adjusted to be a function pointer, which is why you `delegated{func}` and `delegated{func_ptr}` are exactly the same thing and former cannot be smaller.

Wrap the function call inside a function object (lambda, if you so prefer) to avoid the overhead of the function pointer.

---

If you would like to prevent the accidental use of the adjusted/decayed function pointer case when user tries to pass a function, then you could use a deleted overload for function references. I don't know how that could be achieved with CTAD, but if you provide a function interface, it could be done like this:

```
constexpr auto
make_delegated(std::invocable auto CbT)
{
    return delegated{std::move(CbT)};
}

template<class... Args>
constexpr auto
make_delegated(auto (&cb)(Args...)) = delete;
```

---

Edit: Combining ideas with [Human-Compiler's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68927095/2079303)

```
template <auto CbT>
constexpr auto
make_delegated_fun() { 
  return delegated{ []{ CbT(); } };
}

constexpr auto
make_delegated(std::invocable auto CbT)
{
    return delegated{std::move(CbT)};
}

template<class... Args>
constexpr auto
make_delegated(auto (&cb)(Args...)) {
    // condition has to depend on template argument;
    // just false would cause the assert to trigger without overload being called.
    static_assert(!std::is_reference_v<decltype(cb)>, "please use make_delegated_fun");
};


auto from_func1 = make_delegated(func);        // fails to compile
auto from_func2 = make_delegated_fun<func>();  // OK
auto from_func_ptr = make_delegated(func_ptr); // OK, pointer overhead
auto from_lambda = make_delegated([](){});     // OK
auto from_functor = make_delegated(MyFunc{});  // OK
```

Caveat, this would prevent following, and the example wouldn't work using `make_delegated_fun` either so the message would be misleading. The example could easily be rewritten to use function pointers or capturing lambda though:

```
auto& fun_ref = condition ? fun1 : fun2;
make_delegated(fun_ref);       // fails to compile, suggests make_delegated_fun
make_delegated_fun<fun_ref>(); // fails to compile, not constexpr
make_delegated(&fun_ref);      // OK, pointer overhead
```

Comment: Just a heads-up that deleting the `auto (&cb)(Args...)` overload does not necessarily detect every use, though it's probably the closest approach possible. If anyone explicitly uses the form `&func`, then it will construct a `delegated` from a function-pointer -- despite the function itself being known at compile-time.

Comment: @Frank Found an example that seems to work in my basic testing.

Comment: @Human-Compiler Yes, the use of function pointer is intentionally allowed when used explicitly. It's useful when the value isn't compiletime constant. I don't think detecting unnecessary use of `&func` would be easy within the language. Maybe achievable with static analysis.

Comment: Yeah, `&func` leading down the same path as any old function pointer is absolutely reasonable from my point of view.

Comment: Note that `make_delegated` with the `static_assert`  sadly makes a program ill-formed, no diagnostic required, as it is a template specialization with no possible valid instantiation.  Making the static assert seem to be dependent on the template argument fools the compiler, but the C++ standard is not fooled.  It demands that all template functions can be instantiated with some set of arguments, no matter how "tricky" you get in attempting to fool the compiler.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Oh bummer. Do you have a well-formed idea for custom error message on call to deleted overload?

Comment: @eerorika You can do something stupid, like have a possibly trait that is actually private where in theory a specialization of it could make your code compile for a specific type.  Ie, language lawyer your way around it.  But that gets dumb.  Or just accept that you are willing to risk IF;NDR for better error messages.  (In my opinion, we need to add a message to `=delete`, saying "if this is selected for overload resolution, tell the programmer what went wrong").

Comment: That's what `std::integral_constant` is useful for.

Comment: BTW: Your detection of function-pointers is broken. Try e.g. a `noexcept`-function. Suggestion: Use `std::is_function`, `std::is_member_function` and `std::remove_pointer` to make the appropriate concept.

Answer (score 1):

Passing the function pointer as a template argument does not require any space at runtime. For example:

```cpp
template <auto F>
struct delegated_erased {
    template <typename... argument_t>
    auto operator()(argument_t&&... argument){
        F(std::forward<argument_t>(argument)...);
    }
};
```

```
auto from_func = delegated_erased<func>{};
std::cout << "func: " << sizeof(from_func) << "\n"; // 1
```

With a helper function, you can combine this with your code:

```
template <typename result, typename ... argument>
delegated<result> make_delegated(result(&)(argument...)) = delete;

template <typename T>
delegated<T> make_delegated(T f) {
    return delegated{std::move(f)};
};

template <auto F>
delegated_erased<F> make_delegated(){
    return {};
}
```

Which allows you to do:

```
    auto from_func = make_delegated<func>();
    //auto from_func = make_delegated(func); // error: call to deleted function 'make_delegated'
    auto from_func_ptr = make_delegated(func_ptr);
    auto from_lambda = make_delegated([](){});
    auto from_functor = make_delegated(MyFunc{});
```

Comment: How would I use this with a lambda, function, std::function, function pointer, etc...?

Comment: You can use a helper function, see my updated answer. It's not the same API but it works

Answer (score 1):

The only way to really remove the "storage" from a function like this is to use the value at compile-time. The only real way to accomplish this is through a non-type template argument.

A factory function could do this easily with little changes, and keeps the implementation simple. You just need to accept the callable object as a template non-type argument -- such as an `auto` parameter, so that its known at compile-time without any storage requirements.

One way to perform this is to just use your lambda-wrapping solution with the existing code:

```cpp
template <auto Fn>
auto make_delegated() { 
  return delegated{ []{ Fn(); } };
}
```

Then the following works:

```cpp
auto from_func = make_delegated<&func>();
std::cout << "func: " << sizeof(from_func) << "\n";
```

this yields the correct value:

```
func: 1
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jdxo1MGYv)</kbd>

---

As an alternative measure, you could also require the user to wrap the function itself in a sentinel type that carries the data:

```cpp
template <auto Fn>
struct empty_func{
  auto operator()() { return Fn(); }
};
```

This would be almost equivalent to using a lambda, though the user instead only has to do:

```cpp
auto from_func = delegated{empty_func<&func>{}};
```

The point is just that the function needs to be carried at compile-time somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I did mention in the question that for this to be a workable solution, it would need to come alongside something that prevents (or at least warn) users from using `delegated{func}`, which will be the path of least resistance.

Comment: Passing a function to a constructor argument changes it from being known at compile-time in the conventional sense as soon as it is used as a parameter -- so, strictly speaking, using a constructor for this is not possible without _some_ change in flow. The only way to change this is to make the function to be passed as a template non-type template argument. If you want to warn on it, you could always mark a specific constructor for function pointers as deprecated with a warning to use the utility.

Comment: @Frank I put up a separate alternative. The only real solution to remove the size will be to carry the function at compile-time, so an alternative is to use a sentinel-like wrapper `struct` that just holds it in the type. This isn't drastically different than using a lambda, and it still requires some changes to the caller -- but I'm not sure you can do much better than this without at least requiring the user to _always_ use a different interface. You could always just make the user need to use a `make_delegated` factory everywhere so it remains consistent.